# How to change one element style when another is hovered (repost)

Tags: css

Sorry for making things unclear last time, it really was code dump because I didn't know how to explain what was happening. Good news, I fixed it now. However now I a problem with CSS. I am trying to change background colour of a table row () when hovered over a button (my code doesn't work). The css is provided below. The problem is at the buttom of the CSS (the two hover styles): Please tell me what I am doing wrong, I searched for answers for so long however I have not come up with a proper solution.

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
header{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
table{
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#myTable{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
th,td{
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
.nthChild{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
#nlRow th{
    border-top: 0px;
}
input{
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#numeracyCredits, #literacyCredits{
    width: 30%;
}
.button{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 15%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color: #c4c2c2;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.button:hover + .nthChild{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: can you please include also your sample html having the button and the sample table

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML as well

Comment: Don't repost closed questions. [edit] the existing question to improve it so it can be reviewed and re-opened.

Comment: It is a different question from before, I don't know why you would close the question without out proof. I stated (repost) because it's related to the previously asked question. I even stated that I got the last problem working and now I have a new problem, I hope the question gets reposted

Answer (score 0):

the `.nthChild` of what? you should put the parent or whatever from that .nthChild. Or else if you give it a class or an id use that in stead of `.nthChild` then it should work.